# how to display selected items stored in database in list view while edit record?

Tags: java, php, codeigniter-3

the problem i cant catch the acomp_types list in modal_form to highlight the items from  ajax request

i get the items selected from table by passing myID, and the items succesfuly returned in ajax request
the ajax response is

```
[{"acomp_type_id":"1"},{"acomp_type_id":"2"},{"acomp_type_id":"3"},{"acomp_type_id":"4"},{"acomp_type_id":"5"},{"acomp_type_id":"6"},{"acomp_type_id":"7"},{"acomp_type_id":"8"},{"acomp_type_id":"9"}]
```

the ajax request

```
 $('#modal_form').on('shown.bs.modal', function () { 
          //================ get selected items in tourist_accompanying_types and highligt by yellow ==========
          var myID=id;
          $.ajax({
url : "<?php echo base_url('index.php/tourist_facilities/highlight_selected_items')?>/",
type: "GET",
dataType: "json",
data:{id:myID},
success: function(selected_items) {
    //selected_items = JSON.parse(selected_items); // Convert to array
    // Traverse through the modal form and find the element with class "acomp_types"
var $acomp_types = $("#modal_form").find(".acomp_types");

$acomp_types.each(function() {
var item_id = $(this).data("acomp_type_id");
$(this).attr("data-selected_item", item_id);
if ($.inArray(item_id, selected_items) !== -1) {
$(this).addClass("selected");
}
});
}
});
       });
//================ get selected items in tourist_accompanying_types and highligt by yellow ==========
   }
```

the function highlight_selected_items

```
public function highlight_selected_items() {
        //this function to search tourist_accompanying_types by id from ajax request and send back the items
        //to ajax then higeliste seleted by yellow mark
        $id = $this->input->get('id'); 
        $selected_items = $this->db->query("SELECT acomp_type_id FROM tourist_accompanying_types where tf_ID=$id")->result_array();
        echo json_encode($selected_items);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

i want share my success code that fix the issue
i can now highlight the selected items stored in database by yellow mark
here is the change

```
 success: function(selected_items) {
 // Loop through each object in the selected_items array
$.each(selected_items, function(index, item) {
// Get the acomp_type_id value of each object
var acomp_type_id = item.acomp_type_id;
// Do something with the acomp_type_id value
//console.log(acomp_type_id);
        var selectElement = document.getElementById("acomp_types");
        var selectedOption = selectElement.querySelector("option[value='" + acomp_type_id + "']");
        selectedOption.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
});
```